# How to Distinguish Between Private and Public Classes in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm using web pack to package a library.
We have multiple ES6 classes, in this fashion:

*/src/Lib.js*

```
import HelperClass from './HelperClass.js';
class Lib {
  method1() {...}
}
```

*/src/HelperClass.js*

```
class HelperClass {
  doSth() {...}
}
```

Packaging with webpack works, we end up with one file `lib.js` that contains Lib and HelperClass as `var Lib = ...`.

How can I hide the HelperClass from the global namespace (e.g. make it a private class) with webpack?

*UPDATE:*

Now I'm running into an issue with importing the HelperClass! I uploaded a sample project https://github.com/benmarten/webpack_es6_test

This line:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__Helper_js___default.a.doSth();
```

results in:

```
[Error] TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__Helper_js___default.a.doSth is not a function. (In '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__Helper_js___default.a.doSth()', '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__Helper_js___default.a.doSth' is undefined)
method1 (lib.js:92)
Global Code (index.htm:6)
```

Comment: Webpack only expose what you export from the entry point and in the example you gave there is no export, therefore nothing is exposed. Furthermore your `HelperClass.js` does not export anything either, so you would not be able to import it in `Lib.js`. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: gotya, let me test that out in a sample app. thx ;)

Comment: Updated, please take a look, it only works half way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a library with webpack you expose everything that is exported in your entry point, everything else is not accessible from outside but you can use it within your code. If you want to use anything from another file, you still need to export it, because the files are still modules. Just because there is an export, does not mean it becomes a global. Only the exports in the entry specified in the `webpack.config.js` will be exposed.

Export the Helper in `HelperClass.js`:

```
class Helper {
  static doSth() {
    console.log('helper:doSth');
  }
}

export default Helper;
```

Then import it in `Lib.js`:

```
import Helper from './HelperClass.js';

class Lib {
  static method1() {
    Helper.doSth();
  }
}

export default Lib;
```

Now the default export of your bundle will be the `Lib` class and you can use `Helper` inside it without exposing it.

You should also read the [Authoring Libraries Guides](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).

Comment: Thanks, `export default Helper;` solved it.
Now the only problem I have is that I can only access my library with `lib.default.method1();` but ideally I want it to be: `lib.method1();` Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the Authoring Libraries Guide only covers the case of `export function` not of exporting es6 classes ;)

Comment: It's literally the same thing, you might want to read [Exploring ES6 - The basics of ES6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_basics-of-es6-modules) to understand the module system. Also this is not Java, don't use classes everywhere. A free function is much more appropriate than a static method in most cases. Then you can use a named export as in the webpack docs. But if you insist on using classes you can use: `export const method1 = Lib.method1;`, by the way you'll lose the context of `this` and it's equivalent to having defined a regular function in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using UMD preset and the plugins
"add-module-exports", "transform-es2015-modules-umd". Full example here: https://github.com/benmarten/webpack_es6_test